# Auto complete MVC View path

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am working in the JetBrains PhpStorm IDE and I use the "Mark directory as" to mark my public resource folder.
This is working perfect with the public resources.

I was wondering if thats also possible for my App views, I already marked my "views" directory as *Resource* but that didn't do anything.

So to be clear I mean, Now I have to type the path myself 
I want the path to autocomplete with the **views** directory as the root

```cs
protected function view($view, $data = [])
{
    require_once "../app/views/" . $view . ".php";
}


$this->view("path/to/my/views");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible as far as I can see. Closest discussion on PhpStorm tracker is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3468 but that wouldn't help much.

Comment: Awh okay thank you for your reply :).I thought maybe it's possible because when I open a Laravel project it actually does complete Model/View/Controller names.

Comment: @RobHutten That's because of **Laravel plugin** -- it injects certain completion helpers in parameters of certain method/function calls. Maybe such plugin exists for your framework as well? P.S. You can always inject "File Reference" manually that will allow file name completion .. but it needs to be done manually in every single place right now (and such injection lasts for a session only). Please check completion helpers plugins -- some of them allow quite advanced things so may help (show a list of what plugins you have tried)

Comment: @RobHutten https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20028 is about having such injections more permanent. On related note: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35166 (but that's more for JS)

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much for the information! I'm using my own MVC framework right now so I will look into "Completion Helpers" I'll post here again if I found a solution! Thank you again :)